# not able to put the values in the MDC

Tags: java, logging, wicket, mdc

I am trying to log few values in the `onBeginRequest()` of `RequestCycle()` in wicket. 
But the values are not being logged in the debug file. I am putting the values in the MDC in `RequestCycleListeners()`.

Following is the code:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener()
{       
public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle) 
{                   
  if( cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest() instanceof HttpServletRequest )
  {
    HttpServletRequest containerRequest = 
        (HttpServletRequest)cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest();

    MDC.put("serverName", containerRequest.getServerName());
    MDC.put("sessionId",  containerRequest.getSession().getId());

    LOGGER.debug("logging from RequestCycleListeners() !!!");
    WebClientInfo webClientInfo = new WebClientInfo(RequestCycle.get());
    System.out.println(webClientInfo.getUserAgent());
    System.out.println("webClientInfo.getProperties().getBrowserVersionMajor() " +containerRequest.getRemoteAddr());
}
```

};

I am expecting 'serverName', 'sessionId' to be logged in the debug file.

I have added this `listener` in the class which is extending the `WebApplication`.

I am using log4j.xml the `DEBUG appender` is looks as below:

```
<appender name="DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601} %t %5p] %m -- %X{serverName} -- %X{sessionId} -- %X{portNumber}%n"/>
  </layout>
  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN"/>
  </filter>
</appender>
```

and we are defining scope in root tag :

```
<root>
   <priority value="INFO" />
   <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
   <appender-ref ref="DEBUG" />
   <appender-ref ref="ERROR" />
</root>
```

Comment: @Buurman: Its a logging mechanism. You can see more here http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html

Comment: What logging framework are you using underneath slf4j? log4j, logback, java.util.logging, commons logging?

Comment: @superEb: for now log4j

Comment: @RamDuttShukla Could you add your `log4j` configuration and some sample logging from you app to the question please? It may help. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan: Added the log4j.xml configuration.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Typically, MDC values are only output to logs if you include MDC keys in your logging pattern via configuration. Since slf4j is just a facade, you need to have framework-specific support and configuration underneath slf4j to make use of MDC. Read slf4j's notes on that [here](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html).

So, for example, if you're using log4j as the impl underneath slf4j, then you would need log4j config (ConversionPattern) like:

```
%d %-5p [%c] [%X{serverName} %X{sessionId}] %m%n
```

Where `%X{serverName} %X{sessionId}` is the relevant part that pulls values from the MDC.

[Here](https://github.com/vraa/blog/blob/master/_posts/2009-11-02-log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code.md)'s a pretty good example using log4j without sl4j. See notes on `X` Conversion Character in log4j javadoc [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Note that pattern syntax for logback is identical. See specifics for logback [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

Also note that best practice for MDC (which uses a `ThreadLocal` under-the-hood) is to clear the context (remove the values you put in the map) when the context is no longer in scope. That typically means calling `remove` or `clear` in a `finally` block, like:

```
try {
    //...
    MDC.put("key1", value1);
    MDC.put("key2", value2);
    //...
} finally {
    //this
    MDC.remove("key1");
    MDC.remove("key2");
    //or this
    MDC.clear();
}
```

This is especially important if the thread that holds the MDC belongs to a pool for later reuse. You certainly don't want to unintentionally log invalid context values since that will just cause confusion.

### EDIT

Your log4j configuration seems a little odd, for the following reasons:

1. You are naming your appenders after log levels, which may cause confusion
2. Your `RollingFileAppender` does not define a file
3. Your `root` logger will log to 3 different appenders, one of which is named `DEBUG`, but it is configured to only log `INFO` level and greater (based on the `priority` tag), so debug statements will not be logged

Unless you have some specific categories configured separately that are not shown, I would guess that *none* of your `LOGGER.debug` statements are being logged, regardless of your attempt to use MDC.

Comment: Just adding to answer by superEb, logback manual has it on how to use MDC http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Comment: I have tried the same way you are suggesting in your answer by referring the veera-sundar's blog, But the issue is somehow different

Comment: I am accepting this answer because the explanation is quite helpful. Though it is not having the correct answer but it helps me to get the answer.

Comment: @RamDuttShukla - I notice you unaccepted my answer. Please see the additions I made to the EDIT section. It may help you with your logging problems.

Comment: Yes, the reason of not logging was the <root> tag. You are right. Now I will again accept the answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that if you are using **AsyncAppender**, clearing **MDC** from your thread won't protect you, since the log event and MDC handling happens in the AsyncAppender's thread. See also [this related bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50486)

Unfortunately, in v**1.2.17** the latest released version of the EOLed log4j-1.x, the AsyncAppender's Dispatcher-Thread does not clear the MDC upon stopping either.

Since, the AsyncAppender/Dispatcher is fairly simple, it's easy to patch it by putting

```
finally
{
    MDC.clear();
}
```

at the try-block in **org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender.Dispatcher.run()** method.

Of course, one can also workaround this by not using AsyncAppender when executing in a ServletContainer.