# how to print mdc value in logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, atg, mdc

I'm not getting mdc value in logback

can you please help me

Java Code:

```
       String traceId = MDC.get(getJlgConfiguration().getTraceId());
        String sessionId = MDC.get(getJlgConfiguration().getSessionId());
```

Logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60" debug="true">

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %class{0}.%M %L, ole-session-id:%mdc{ole-session-id:-NONE}, jlg-trace-id:%mdc{jlg-trace-id:-NONE} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You snippet is get() ?
You need to put (Key, Val) and then log and then remove. If you wanna format with your own layout, you'll need to know the key.

See the sample on http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use %X instead of %mdc

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %class{0}.%M %L, ole-session-id:%X{ole-session-id:-NONE}, jlg-trace-id:%X{jlg-trace-id:-NONE} - %msg%n
```

Checkout the documentation for more information
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Comment: Still am not getting value! if I use the above code

Comment: I just see it now. Why do you use an Encoder and not an appender? And the pattern is not in the CONSOLE appender confugred

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help, [not able to put the values in the MDC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492834/14669455)

Basically if for example, you're using log4j as the impl underneath slf4j, then you would need log4j config (ConversionPattern) like:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5p| %t | [ole-session-id:%X{ole-session-id:-NONE}, jlg-trace-id:%X{jlg-trace-id:-NONE}] | %logger{36} | %m %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```